# Can´t get an object attribute value

Tags: javascript, object, attributes

I got this object *message* in javascript and console.log(message) throws:

[image]

I can access(or print) any of those variables except **ctrlAlerta.descripcion**
using `console.log(message.codAlerta)`
But `console.log(message.ctrlAlerta.descripcion)` is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

In this case *ctrlAlerta.descripcion* is the name of the property. So you cant use dot to access this, because it is a reserved character. Try:

```
console.log(message["ctrlAlerta.descripcion"])
```